# Convert a nested array to a matrix in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, matrix

When converting a nested array to a matrix in Ruby, the matrix ends up with an extra `[]` around the values, compared to simply creating a matrix from scratch.

```
> require 'matrix'

> matrix1 = Matrix[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
> p matrix1
```

> => Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

```
> nested_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
> matrix2 = Matrix[nested_array]
> p matrix2
```

> => Matrix[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]

Is there a way to avoid the extra square brackets when building from an array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
matrix2 = Matrix[*nested_array]
p matrix2
=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The asterisk (`*`) there is called the "splat operator," and it essentially can be used to treat an array (`nested_array` in this case) as if it weren't an array, but rather as if its elements were individual elements/arguments.